# Nexus Sonatype return 404 not found after installation

Tags: maven, repository, nexus, sonatype

after installing Nexus Sonatype OSS (3.2.1) to manage maven plugin, when I want to access my Nexus user interface using this url http://localhost:8081/nexus as the doc said here https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/running.html, I got 404 not found. But when I type just http://localhost:8081, I got the repository manager front page.

How could I do to access the nexus user interface please ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your source https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/running.html is about Nexus 2.14, but you installed 3.2.1.

The URL changed from Nexus 2 to Nexus 3.

Comment: you are totally right. I was reading the documentation of nexus 2.14. In the new version of nexus, the user interface http://localhost:8081/nexus doesn't exist. Thanks for your answer.